# Vaadin combobox validation

Tags: validation, combobox, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to validate the value of a combobox with Vaadin. My goal is to avoid committing the form with the selected object's 'myIntegerAttribute' field setted to null. Supose that the combobox stores 'MyBean' class objects.

I'm using a "FilterableListContainer" to bind the data.
I tried this, but it seems that the validator is not being fired:

```
List<MyBean> myBeans = getMyBeansList();
FilterableListContainer filteredMyBeansContainer = new FilterableListContainer<MyBean>(myBeans);
comboBox.setContainerDataSource(filteredMyBeansContainer);
comboBox.setItemCaptionPropertyId("caption");
...
comboBox.addValidator(getMyBeanValidator("myIntegerAttribute"));
...
private BeanValidator getMyBeanValidator(String id){
    BeanValidator validator = new BeanValidator(MyBean.class, id);//TrafoEntity
    return validator;
}

class MyBean {
    String caption;
    Integer myIntegerAttribute;
    ...
}
```

I don't want to avoid selecting null value in the combobox.

How can I avoid commiting the null value?

Comment: Are you using a binder for your form or manually adding components to a layout? Showing the full code including the "committing" part would help with understanding your scenario.

Comment: Yes, I've added more details to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was implementing the validator in the wrong way. I created a class implementing Vaadin's 'Validator' class:

```
public class MyBeanValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public void validate(Object value) throws InvalidValueException {
        if (!isValid(value)) {
            throw new InvalidValueException("Invalid field");
        }
    }
    private boolean isValid(Object value) {
        if (value == null || !(value instanceof MyBean)
                || ((MyBean) value).getMyIntegerAttribute() == null ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And used it in the combobox:

```
combobox.addValidator(new MyBeanValidator());
```

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: That's certainly one way to do it, if you don't want to use BeanValidator.

Answer (score 1):

In Vaadin 7, you would use [NullValidator](https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.7/com/vaadin/data/validator/NullValidator.html) to fail validation when the user's selection is null:

```
    NullValidator nv = new NullValidator("Cannot be null", false);
    comboBox.addValidator(nv);
```

To fail validation when a member of the object that corresponds to the user's selection is null, using BeanValidator you would include the @NotNull JSR-303 annotation on the bean class:

```
public class MyBean {

    String caption;

    @NotNull
    int myIntegerAttribute;

    // etc...
}
```

Are you using the FilterableListContainer from Viritin? I'm not sure why that would be preventing the validator from being used, but can you explain why you are using it with a combo box?

Comment: That wont work, because the combobox value is never null, the null value could be 'myIntegerAttribute' property of 'MyClass' type object. I use FilterableListContainer to bind 'myBean' values to the fields of my form (obviously I have more fields apart from the combobox). I think that the problem is related with that as you said

Comment: @Ortzi : Answer has been updated to include how to handle null bean members.